# How can I invoke a method on every instance in a cluster in jboss 4.2.3?

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing, jboss-4.2.x

From a pojo annotated with @Service and @Management I want to invoke a method on every instance in my cluster.

```
@Service(objectName=myClass.OBJECT_NAME)
@Management(MyInterface.class)
public class MyClass implements myInterface
{
  @Override
  public void callEverywhere () throws Exception {
     final ArrayList results = partition.getHAPartition().callMethodOnCluster(OBJECT_NAME,"methodName", new Object[] {}, new Class[] {}, false);
  }
  public String myMethod() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

results in the method not getting called.  Under the hood it looks like Im getting a `NoHandlerForRPC` instead of calling the method.

I know I can use an `HAServiceMBeanSupport` but have reasons for wanting to use POJOs.

Can I do this with pojos in jboss 4.2.3?

Comment: How are you getting the partition?